# Hackage documentation incosistent with my installed package?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Having package installed by cabal:

```
All the requested packages are already installed:
tagsoup-0.12.8
```

I try to compile:

```
module TagSoupSample where
import Data.Text
import Text.HTML.TagSoup
import Text.StringLike

foo :: Text -> [Tag Text]
foo = parseTags
```

which results in:

```
tagsoup.hs:7:7:
No instance for (StringLike Text)
  arising from a use of `parseTags'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (StringLike Text)
In the expression: parseTags
In an equation for `foo': foo = parseTags
```

However, http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/tagsoup/0.12.8/doc/html/Text-StringLike.html#t:StringLike says such instance exists. Why I can't find any other instance than StringLike String?

```
Prelude Data.Text> :info Text.StringLike.StringLike
class (Data.Typeable.Internal.Typeable a,
       Eq a) => Text.StringLike.StringLike a where
  Text.StringLike.empty :: a
  Text.StringLike.cons :: Char -> a -> a
  Text.StringLike.uncons :: a -> Maybe (Char, a)
  Text.StringLike.toString :: a -> String
  Text.StringLike.fromString :: String -> a
  Text.StringLike.fromChar :: Char -> a
  Text.StringLike.strConcat :: [a] -> a
  Text.StringLike.strNull :: a -> Bool
  Text.StringLike.append :: a -> a -> a
        -- Defined in `Text.StringLike'
instance Text.StringLike.StringLike String
  -- Defined in `Text.StringLike'
```

How can I browse documentation and sources for the package I have installed?

Comment: This might happen if you have multiple versions of `text` installed, and `tagsoup` was compiled against a different version than you are importing.

Comment: But then the other instance would be shown with `:info StringLike`

Comment: Forcing reinstall of Data.Text to matching version helped to solve Warning: Data.Text: could not find link destinations for:
    Data.Text.replicateChar Data.Text.countChar

Comment: I don’t think the version was the culprit, but its rather likely that you did not build the documentation when building `text` the first time. The linking mentioned in the warning is that of HTML links, not of linking programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I browse documentation and sources for the package I have installed?

If you pass `--documentation` to `cabal install`, or set `Documentation: True` in your `.cabal/config` file, `cabal install` will generate documentation for every package that you install. You might have to re-install the packages you are interested in to get documentation for them. You will find the documentation, together with a nice index, in `~/.cabal/share/doc/index.html`.

If you want the documentation to also include highlighted source code, you need to pass `--haddock-hyperlink-source` to `cabal` (or, better, that that option in your config file).